# SteadyFlow extension Chrome

Tags: download-manager

Can steadyflow download manager run on Chrome? I can't integrate steadyflow with Chrome.
Someone help me please?

I'm a new immigrant from windows and now use Kubuntu 14.04.

i'm sorry my english is bad

Comment: What is steadyflow? Where does one get it? Is it an application? A browser extension? Please [edit] your question and add some more details.

Comment: @terdon he explained it fairly well...steadyflow, is a download manager which he said. He asked for chrome support. He should have provided a link in general but the answer was rather easy for those who knew what steadyflow is.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell it was not a reprimand. The question was not clear to me so I requested a clarification, that's all.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. It seemed as though you were reprimanding, my bad for not clarifying first to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link, it looks like the appropriate extension for what you are trying to accomplish.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/chromeflow-steadyflow-chromium-integration-extension-released.html

Comment: Yea chromeflow is the extension needed...that is actually the official extension from the steadyflow team though it doesnt like like it is.